# How to perform click on a string value?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click a variable value which is stored in a string and below is my code.

```
OrderConfirmationData orderConfirmationData= (OrderConfirmationData)Serenity.sessionVariableCalled("OrderConfirmationData");
        int maxtries=0;

        System.out.println("Order is available in NTI" + EfloristConstants.lastname.get());

        List<WebElement> recordcount = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//table[contains(@id,'ctrlDWController1_DWDetails1_gvNTI')]/*/tr[not(contains(@style,'bold'))]"));
        int j=16;
        for(int i=1;i<=recordcount.size();i++) {
            j=j*i;
            String record = "(//table[contains(@id,'ctrlDWController1_DWDetails1_gvNTI')]/*/tr[not(contains(@style,'bold'))]/td)["+j+"]";
            String recipientname= element(By.xpath(record)).getTextValue();

            if(recipientname.equals(orderConfirmationData.getShipFirstName() != null)) {
                System.out.println("Order is available ");  
            }
            j=16;
        }
```

want to click on the recipientname when the, if the condition matches i.e want to perform click inside the If condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below line in if condition:

```
element(By.xpath(record)).click()
```